# Unable to start pritunl container in a kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, pritunl

I have created a pritunl docker container and tried running from my local machine and seems like it is working fine.However i pushed the image to amazon ECR and deployed into kubernetes but i am getting the below error.

**Pod Status:**
`Back-off restarting failed container`

**Pod logs:**
`/bin/start-pritunl: 28: /usr/bin/pritunl: not found`
**
Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV PRITUNL_VERSION=1.32.3805.95

COPY --chown=root:root ["docker-install.sh", "/root"]
RUN bash /root/docker-install.sh

ADD start-pritunl /bin/start-pritunl

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 1194
EXPOSE 1194/udp

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/start-pritunl"]

CMD ["/usr/bin/tail", "-f","/var/log/pritunl.log"]
```

**docker-install.sh file**:

```
set -ex

apt-get update -q
apt-get install -y gnupg wget

echo 'deb http://repo.pritunl.com/stable/apt bionic main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pritunl.list
echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list

apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7568D9BB55FF9E5287D586017AE645C0CF8E292A
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 8E6DA8B4E158C569

apt-get update -q
apt-get install -y locales iptables wget
locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
apt-get upgrade -y -q
apt-get dist-upgrade -y -q

wget --quiet https://github.com/pritunl/pritunl/releases/download/${PRITUNL_VERSION}/pritunl_${PRITUNL_VERSION}-0ubuntu1.jammy_amd64.deb
dpkg -i pritunl_${PRITUNL_VERSION}-0ubuntu1.jammy_amd64.deb || apt-get -f -y install
rm pritunl_${PRITUNL_VERSION}-0ubuntu1.jammy_amd64.deb

wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

apt-get --purge autoremove -y wget
apt-get clean
apt-get -y -q autoclean
apt-get -y -q autoremove
rm -rf /tmp/*
```

**start-pritunl file:**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

[ -d /dev/net ] ||
    mkdir -p /dev/net
[ -c /dev/net/tun ] ||
    mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200

touch /var/log/pritunl.log
touch /var/run/pritunl.pid
/bin/rm /var/run/pritunl.pid

if [ "$1" = "bash" ]; then
    exec "$@"
    exit $?
fi

# allow changing debug mode
if [ -z "$PRITUNL_DEBUG" ]; then
    PRITUNL_DEBUG="false"
fi

# allow changing bind addr
if [ -z "$PRITUNL_BIND_ADDR" ]; then
    PRITUNL_BIND_ADDR="0.0.0.0"
fi

/usr/bin/pritunl set-mongodb ${MONGODB_URI}
/usr/bin/pritunl set app.reverse_proxy ${REVERSE_PROXY}
/usr/bin/pritunl set app.redirect_server ${REDIRECT_SERVER}
/usr/bin/pritunl set app.server_ssl ${SERVER_SSL}
/usr/bin/pritunl set app.server_port ${SERVER_PORT}
/usr/bin/pritunl set local.public_ip ${PUBLIC_IP}
/usr/bin/pritunl start
```

Since i have a feeling that it might be because of the base ubuntu image version 22.04, so i changed it to 20.04 but still the same issue.
Is it because of any permissions issue?

Comment: You should consider putting the content of "docker-install.sh" into your dockerfile as build steps